# page container hasn't height

Tags: css, html, height

I have this site where i have (very resumed):

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <!-- all html in here -->
   </div>
</body>
```

The thing is that i need the page centered (so i cant use float),

And the body has `background:#ddd`, and the container has `background:#fff`,

The problem is that the white background isn't visible unless i set min-height or height to the container in px (or if i set float, but not compatible),

The #container markup is:

```
#contenedor{
    display: block;
    background:  white;
    width: 1024px;
    padding: 44px 2px 2px;
    position: relative; /* is relative so the margin auto works */
    margin: auto;

}
```

Test is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bfzWN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to add `overflow:auto` to your container (`#contenedor`) :

```
#contenedor{
    display: block;
    background:  white;
    width: 1024px;
    padding: 44px 2px 2px;
    position: relative; /* is relative so the margin auto works */
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto; /* ADD THIS LINE */
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/bfzWN/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of floats that aren't cleared. I would add a pseudo element that clears after your contenedor:

```
#contenedor:after {
    content:"\0020";
    display:block;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}
```

Personally, I like this better than the "overflow" trick @tw16 has answered with because if you ever want to position something outside of contenedor, you still can.

Comment: A nice solution, but hindered by the fact it won't work in IE7 and of course it is quite a few lines for something that can be done in one line. But that is like for uber optimisation if you are worried about lines of CSS.

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet pseudo-elements work in IE8+. If you need IE7 support, you should not use this method. Luckily, IE7 only has 2.65% of the global browser marketshare (whereas IE8+ have has 39%), so I personally choose to use this exclusively. Depends on your audience your developing for.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the body to 1024 and center it, this will allow you to float the div.

```
<body style="width: 1024px; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;">
```

.

```
#contenedor {
 display: block;
 background:  white;
 width: 1024px;
 padding: 44px 2px 2px;
 position: relative; /* is relative so the margin auto works */
 margin: auto;
 float: left;
```

}